# Pandoc keep logos and headers/footers from template (ODT)

Tags: templates, markdown, docx, pandoc, odt

So earlier this was working for me. I updated my template with a new version and now I'm only getting a file with the main body text -- no logos/headers.

The template in question is from the Frontiers journals:
http://www.frontiersin.org/Design/zip/Frontiers_Word_Templates.zip

I opened it in Word and saved it as ODT. Before I was getting an ODT file converted from MD with the logos and the messages in header and footer, but not anymore.

I need this, because my collaborators still use Word and we need to use this template.

My xml template file is very simple and doesn't match perfectly the Frontiers template. If anyone else this template would you be so kind and share your xml?

Using the linked docx as reference will (almost) give me the result I want, but it doesn't support different left/right headers/footer which are present in the original docx template and the whole YAML stuff (authors, etc) and tables are not working.

This seems to be a conversion problem from docx to odt. How could I make this template valid odt so I can use tables and captions and keep the custom headers and footers from the original Frontiers template?

Comment: welcome to SO! so... what exactly are you asking? what are you trying to do in word and what in pandoc? please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to convert a document written in markdown into an .odt (or docx if now captions are supported). My problem is that, when using the Frontiers' template saved as .odt as pandoc's --reference-odt, the logo, header and footer are dropped. I want to keep all of that.

Comment: @mariachi - you're better off asking your question as you stated it in the comment above. It seems that the issue is _just_ your logo header and footer missing. So, if you re-phrase the question as that, you might get a better response.